# PHP Log Function Returning NAN

Tags: php

I am using the PHP log function in the calculation below, although it keeps returning NAN. This is a real numeric value - it's related to mortgage calculations and amortization, etc. I am not sure why it is defining the result as 'not a number'. Is there anything I can add to this to force the result to display the actual result? Or is something wrong in the way I am writing this?

```
$payoffTime = -(log(1 - ((128000 * .05) / 1260)) / log(1 + .05));
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: 1 - ((128000 * .05) / 1260) is a negative number. You can't have a log of a negative number.

Comment: `1 - ((128000 * .05) / 1260)` is a negative number, and logs really don't do so well with those; the result is I believe a complex or at least imaginary number. Which is why .NET will *also* throw a nice NaN back in your face in the same case.

Comment: suggest: https://github.com/mkpeacock/PHP-Mortgage-Calculator

Comment: Thanks! Although the following equation is supposed to give the amount of payments needed to pay off a mortgage, and this is what I am using for this. (Sorry something happened with that paste.) This is just the example - http://cl.ly/image/2I0O3G1u3j0V - my values are different. So do you mean that PHP would not be able to calculate an equation like this, since it would be a negative number? Or is there something else I can edit in this that would make it work?

Comment: Example shows interest rate as 0.005 not 0.05 as in your example. Using the correct value would avoid the negative number.

Comment: @markdwhite Wow - something so small. Ha. Thank you! That fixed it. :) (You should add this as the answer and I will be happy to check that for you. :))

Comment: typo- question should jsut be deleted